# How to deploy with Composer and Git without downtime?

Tags: git, deployment, workflow, composer-php

For our project we are using Git to version our code and Composer to handle the dependencies. That work quite well, but for updating or adding a dependency, I haven't found a good workflow.

Let's assume, we want to add feature, that needs some new dependency. We would implement and test it in a feature branch. In this branch, we would update the composer.json file. After finishing the feature, we merge it using a pull request and deploy it with `git pull` on the server. The we would perform the `composer install` to install the new dependencies on the server. The issue with this workflow: for the time between the Git and Composer update, the system might be broken due to missing dependencies.

How would you solve this in a workflow without any downtime and without a maintenance mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I you want to do it manually, one solution is to deploy to a versioned folder on the server and then soft-link that folder to the actual production folder after `composer install` has finished. This way, there's basically zero downtime for your site. For example, your folder structure might look like this:

```
./
../
app/
    /current --> app/versions/01
    /versions
        /01
```

and you point your document root for that website to `app/current`. Then the deploy process might be something like this (you need to change the paths to match you situation):

```
$ cp -r app/versions/01 app/versions/02  # make a new version
$ cd app/versions/02
$ git pull                               # update the new version
$ composer install                       # update new version dependencies
$ ln -sfn app/versions/02 app/current    # make new version live
```

Note that the web server does have to be set up to follow symbolic links. Afterwards, your folder structure will look like this:

```
./
../
app/
    /current --> app/versions/02
    /versions
        /01
        /02
```

As a bonus to this method: if something is wrong with the new version, you can just point the symbolic link back to the original version while you troubleshoot.

If you want to automate this process, there are also deployment tools that will handle this kind of thing for you, such as [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) and [Mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/).

Comment: That is a pretty clever idea and would really enable a "near to zero" downtime. And we might even test drive the newly deployed version before updating the symlink. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking to integrate [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) or [build automation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) into your workflow.

First, be sure to check out the sections on each in PHP: The Right Way: http://www.phptherightway.com/#building_and_deploying_your_application.

You may also wish to look into:

- [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
- [PHPCI](https://www.phptesting.org/)
- https://travis-ci.org/
- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)

Comment: And how do they handle such updates? The only way I could think about solving this scenario was cherry picking the commit with the composer.json update and running the installation before merging the feature branch. But that might still be an issue when updating dependencies to newer versions without backwards compatibility.

Comment: I believe the point of such tools is to automate the process of filling the gap you mention above. Ideally, you push/pull your production-ready commit to that environment and it should automatically be tested and dependencies updated.

Comment: But there is still a time gap between the merge and the composer update. And continuos integration services as I understand them are mor for testing builds and not for deploying them to production.